# Order Facebook page likes by date desc

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like

How can I see my Facebook page likes, but ordered desc by date (the new ones should be the first)?

I got a notification that my page has *2 new likes* -- and I want to see who liked it.

How can I do this?